# can't figure out mod_rewrite for certain pretty url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, dynamic

I am having trouble figuring out how to write this condition I am wanting in my .htaccess file.

I have tried multiple different ways with no success but, here is what I am trying to accomplish. Using apache.

My current url is like this: http://site.com/page?id=123&variable=a-text-like-this
I am wanting to turn it into this: http://site.com/differentpagename/a-text-like-this/

I want to hide the name of the real page and the id and its value.

can someone please help ive spent all night trying to figure this out.

Comment: redirecting is a simple task. But will your script be able to find id by alias?

Comment: I am sorry the confusion. I am not wanting to redirect but do a rewrite. /differentpagename/a-text-like-this/ is not a real page but just what the user sees for the current page /page?id=123&variable=a-text-like-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want. But beware, that id is hard-coded in .htacess, which is very bad. So, you'll need a line for every alias. That's why I asked about transfering alias to id in the script.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule differentpagename/a-text-like-this/ /page?id=123&variable=a-text-like-this [L]
```

Comment: Alright, this is backwards from what I am asking. Using dynamic variables and id I would need to have : RewriteRule differentpagename/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ /page?id=$1&variable=$2 .

Comment: @NoktaVonTavius No, man, this won't work. You must rewrite from pretty URL to the real URL on server. Otherwise Apache won't understand. what script to run.

Comment: Ok, this is what I have ended up with. Since I cant do what I wanted the variable wasnt needed just the id. So RewriteRule differentpagename/([0-9]+)/*/ /page?id=$1. Thanks for the help user4035. Sorry the above comment was edited after u sent a response?

Comment: @NoktaVonTavius You can remove star and slash at the end, keeping just: differentpagename/([0-9]+)/ /page?id=$1